# Function of parameter type in type definition

Tags: julia

Assume I want to store I vector together with its norm. I expected the corresponding type definition to be straightforward:

```
immutable VectorWithNorm1{Vec <: AbstractVector}
    vec::Vec
    norm::eltype(Vec)
end
```

However, this doesn't work as intended:

```
julia> fieldtype(VectorWithNorm1{Vector{Float64}},:norm)
Any
```

It seems I have to do

```
immutable VectorWithNorm2{Vec <: AbstractVector, Eltype}
    vec::Vec
    norm::Eltype
end
```

and rely on the user to not abuse the `Eltype` parameter. Is this correct?

PS: This is just a made-up example to illustrate the problem. It is not the actual problem I'm facing.

Comment: How about storing it as a `Symbol`?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The thing is that you can do run-time check of [whether the function can be applied as a norm](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.applicable) in the __constructor__, but you cannot impose that in the type

Comment: What about `immutable Foo{T}; vec::Vector{T}; norm::T; end` (sorry for the one line definition -- hopefully splitting at the `;` makes sense! You lose the ability to have it be any `AbstractVector`, but do you need that?

Comment: In this case I probably wouldn't need arbitrary `AbstractVector`s, but in my application I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any calculations on a type parameter *currently* do not work
(although I did discuss the issue with Jeff Bezanson at JuliaCon, and he seemed amenable to fixing it).
The problem currently is that the expression for the type of `norm` gets evaluated when the parameterized type is defined, and gets called with a `TypeVar`, but it is not yet bound to a value, which is what you really need it to be called with, at the time that that parameter is actually bound to create a concrete type.

I've run into this a lot, where I want to do some calculation on the number of bits of a floating point type, i.e. to calculate and use the number of `UInt`s needed to store a fp value of a particular precision, and use an `NTuple{N,UInt}` to hold the mantissa.